# Mailbox moves - MSExchange ResourceHealth registry key doesn't exist

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration, exchange-2016

Migrating mailboxes from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016.

It's going excruciatingly slowly, likely because the old and new VMs share the same relatively slow disks, and it keeps getting throttled.

Everything on the internet says to go to  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSExchange ResourceHealth]` and set `MRS` to 0, to disable the throttling.  I've found plenty of posts for both 2013 and 2016 that say to do that.

But I don't have such a registry key. There is no `MSExchange ResourceHealth`.  Has this changed in a newer update?

Exchange 2010 server is version 14.3 (Build 123.4).  Exchange 2016 server is version 15.1 (Build 466.34).

So where is that registry key?  Has that setting moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the registry value you mentioned above I would try to "tune" the Mailbox Replication service. As the service is responsible for moving mailboxes (in your case from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016), importing and exporting .pst files, and restoring disabled and soft-deleted mailboxes.

What I changed in the past to speed up the migration was:

- MaxStallRetryPeriod
- MaxActiveMovesPerSourceServer
- MaxActiveMovesPerTargetServer
- MaxActiveMovesPerTargetMDB
- MaxActiveMovesPerSourceMDB
- ...

You can find more infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963524(v=exchg.141).aspx).